# How to sum the values of not empty <td> elements in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum, html-table

I am trying to make a sum total of all the html inside of `<td>` elements with name='gross_val'. I have following `<td>` elements:

```
<tr><td name="gross_val" align="right" title="gross_val1" ></td></tr>
<tr><td name="gross_val" align="right" title="gross_val2" ></td></tr>
<tr><td name="gross_val" align="right" title="gross_val3" ></td></tr>
<tr><td name="gross_val" align="right" title="gross_val4" ></td></tr>
<tr><td name="gross_val" align="right" title="gross_val5" ></td></tr>
```

All of these `<td>` elements have been dynamically populated with values in them. Some of these `<td>` elements have **gross total values** of the `<tr>` they are inside and some of them have not been populated yet. I just want to sum those `<td>` elements who have been populated with **gross total values**. And then show that value in another `<td>` element.

I have written the following JQuery and Javascript for this:

```
    function computeGrossValTotal() {
        var x = $("td[name='gross_val']");
        var gValues = [];
        $(x).each(function(index) {
            // this line takes up the raw html inside of that td element
            var valc = $(this).html();
            // this line strips all the currency and other characters and symbols
            // off the 'valc' variable and makes it in an integer format
            var val = Number(WC(valc));
            if (val) {
                gValues.push(val);
            }
        });
        // this line adds the values inside of gValues array
        sum = Number(gValues.reduce(add, 0));
        alert(sum);
    }
    $(document).on("keyup", function() {
        computeGrossValTotal();
    });
   function WC(x) { return Number(x.match(/(?:\d+|\.)/g).join("")); }
   function add(a, b) {return a + b;}
```

The problem I am facing is that **sum** does not alert unless all the `<td>` elements have some html inside of them. I cannot get to remove the empty td elements from the equation. Please can someone guide me as to how to only sum the `<td>` elements who have some value inside of them.

Comment: "WC is not defined".  Please provide the code for that function.

Comment: `function WC(x) {
    return Number(x.match(/(?:\d+|\.)/g).join(""));
}`

Comment: Maybe try:

var valc = $(this).html() || "0"; 

Otherwise, please post the WC code

Comment: Also, please modify your HTML so as to illustrate what you mean by "Some of these `<td>` elements have gross total values of the <tr> they are inside".

Comment: Do you get any error on the console when the alert fails to appear?

Comment: @ Traktor53 yes the error says **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null**

Comment: If there are no matches, `x.match()` returns `null`, not an empty array. You need to check for that before trying to call `join`.

Comment: In the line `sum = Number(gValues.reduce(add, 0));`, `add` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WC` needs to check that `x.match()` finds something, so it doesn't call `join` on `null`.

```
function WC(x) {
    var nums = x.match(/(?:\d+|\.)/g);
    if (nums) {
        return Number(nums.join(''));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar. This is solution is perfect. I now understand what had I done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

x.match([[regex]]) will either return an array of matches or null if it doesn't match the regex.

When you have an element without html, you and you do $(element).html(), you will get an empty string so x.match([[regex]]) will not match your empty string and return null. 
Then you will try to do .join("") on a null and you will get an error.

As I posted in a comment, you can either do something like:

```
var valc = $(this).html() || "0";
```

Or, In your case, I would modify the WC function to guard it from trying to execute .join on a null and make it return a 0 (since it won't affect your addition) in the case that .match returns null.